# SSD caching using bcache or dm-cache on kernel 2.6.32-042stab104.1

Tags: centos, filesystems, cache, kernel, openvz

I'm looking to use bcache or dm-cache with the latest OpenVZ kernel (2.6.32-042stab104.1) on CentOS 6. Unfortunately, dm-cache and bcache are part of kernel 3.10, but I know the OpenVZ kernel has a lot of functionality backported into it. Would it be possible to use either of these in this situation? If so, roughly how would I go about that?

I looked into Flashcache, but I've heard bcache and dm-cache perform much better.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dm-cache wasn't merged until 3.9 and bcache wasn't merged until 3.10. EnhanceIO is a fork of flashcache which some optimizations that also is available on 3.10.

There have been a lot of advancements since 2.6.32 in the kernel and there aren't any backports for these features in the RHEL6 kernel which OpenVZ is based off of.

OpenVZ will be releasing a beta of RHEL7 (3.10) in the next few months and most likely a stable release soon after that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is module openvz / centos, at least for 2.6.32-042stab112.15-el6-openvz version. You can check with:

```
root@mu2:~# fgrep CONFIG_DM_CACHE /boot/config-2.6.32-042stab112.15-el6-openvz
CONFIG_DM_CACHE=m
CONFIG_DM_CACHE_MQ=m
CONFIG_DM_CACHE_CLEANER=m
```

not sure about host node userspace utils on Centos 6 host, but on host with Debian 8, it looks like some support included:

```
root@mu2:~# lvconvert --help|grep -i cache
lvconvert [--type cache[-pool]|--cache]
        [--cachepool CacheDataLogicalVolume[Path]]
        [--cachemode CacheMode]
        [--poolmetadata CacheMetadataLogicalVolume[Path] |
        [Cache|CacheDataPool]LogicalVolume[Path]
```

I've not used it myself yet, but hope this gonna help u.